# I need to gather 15 consecutive days of records even if some days have none, not just the last 15

Tags: mysql

I have a table with dates and several columns of data. Most weeks every day will have entries but some will not. I have a chart that I want to load the last 15 days of accumulated data into but it only displays 14 days if a day is missing. How do I get 15 actual dates rather than the last 15 calander spanning dates?

EDIT: My solution was adding this line below to the WHERE clause that eliminates Sundays from my result:

`AND dayofweek( date ) > 1`

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS days,
       SUM(act_del_stops+act_pu_stops) AS stops, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(on_road_hrs))) AS on_rh,  
       date AS date3
       FROM service_data 
       WHERE date >= (select MAX(date) FROM service_data)  - INTERVAL 15 DAY
       GROUP BY date  
       ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: You need to outer join with a source of all dates, a calendar table or a calculated list of dates on-the-fly.

Comment: I got it working with DRapps help by adding a where clause to eliminate Sunday's. Thanks to whomever for the negative thingy up there. I was just asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option to dynamically build your calendar of every possible day within the 15-day range is with MySQL Recursive CTE.  In the example below, the union allows the recursion to be based on the query above the union which is "sets" the initial values.  Ex: the Select current_Date(), 1 will get whatever the current date is and also 1 for the first record.  The UNION portion re-calls the same alias "MyCal" by subtracting 1 day from its current date start, but adding 1 to the day number UNTIL the day number gets to your 15 day cutoff.

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
MyCal (calDate, dayNum) AS
(
   SELECT current_date(), 1 
   union all
   SELECT date_add( calDate, interval -1 day ), dayNum +1 
      from MyCal 
      where dayNum < 20 
)
SELECT * FROM MyCal
```

Now that you have that as the basis of calendar days to work with, just LEFT-JOIN to your production data to get the other parts. So, leaving the With Recursive MyCal, just change the part `select * from MyCal` above to

```
select
      m.CalDate,
      sd.days,
      sd.stops,
      sd.on_rh
   from
      ( select * from MyCal ) m
         left join
         ( SELECT 
                 date AS date3,
                 COUNT(name) AS days,
                 SUM(act_del_stops+act_pu_stops) stops, 
                 SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(on_road_hrs))) on_rh
              FROM 
                 service_data 
              WHERE 
                 date >= date_add( current_date(), interval -20 day )
              GROUP BY 
                 date ) sd
            on m.CalDate = sd.date3
   where
      -- this will exclude Sundays
      dayofweek( m.CalDate ) > 1
   order by
      m.CalDate DESC
   limit 15
```

Sorry about the prior issues, been a bit unclear from current medication drowziness.  Anyhow, above should now be good.  I changed to that each component of the query is a pre-aggregate first, THEN joined the results.  The MyCal table is the primary to qualify ONLY the 15 days in question.  The LEFT JOIN to your query only pre-aggregates the last 15 days and no longer plows through every date.

Comment: I can't wrap my brain around that but I did try it in PHPMyAdmin and it kicked out this error... #1054 - Unknown column 'MyCal.CalDate' in 'field list'

Comment: @drodsher, updated, sorry, my bad on alias "m" vs "MyCal" reference.  If it works for you I will edit this answer and provide a better scenario of HOW it is working.

Comment: Its only grabbing 10 days. Here's a screencap... https://imgur.com/a/X4aOEBh

Comment: @drodsher, remove the WHERE clause (revised my post).  By pulling there WHERE clause to restrict the date of details, that changed it to an INNER JOIN.  Should be good after that.

Comment: unfortunately that pulls every date in the table. And the calDate is displaying NULL now.

Comment: I think I have it with a LIMIT. It has issues with something because it's erroring and it only displays 10 CalDate dates and then nulls the last 5 but my date3 column functions. The error in PHPMyAdmin is  Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect time value: '' and its about 25 in a row. The results are linked here:  https://imgur.com/WMynJCQ

Comment: @drodsher, sorry about the wrong order of table/left-join.  Revised and explained how/why in answer.

Comment: I feel like I'm pestering you at this point but I'm getting this now...#1054 - Unknown column 'sd.date' in 'on clause'. I changed it to sd.days to no avail.

Comment: @drodsher, sorry, sd.date3... man medications are messing me up today bad :)

Comment: sooo close. It has 15 dates but some have no data. I need all of the 15 last days with data in the table. https://imgur.com/oORJq5W

Comment: @drodsher, if you run your query on its own, does THAT show data for the missing dates?  If not, that is the issue.  We cant make the query come up with data for dates if such data does not exist.  Even your data capture/print showed no values for Feb 26, nor Mar 5.  So the query IS actually working

Comment: DRapp, those dates don't have any data. Every sunday will not have data. Every day that goes by that I don't upload new data will be blanks as well. I have a chart that I build from the data pulled with this query. Currently it looks like this screenshot. It works fine except for the fact that the Sundays having no data screws up my limit 15. I need there to always be the two weeks back but I want it to start on the same day it ends so I can have realist data for my trend lines. https://imgur.com/PrUospa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252449/discussion-between-drapp-and-drodsher).

Answer (score 0):

As @Stu mentions, you need to join to a table that includes all of that data. One way to do that is to create a temporary table, like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE numbers (n INT);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14);
```

You could then perform the outer join against that table. Perhaps like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS days,
   SUM(act_del_stops+act_pu_stops) AS stops, 
   SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(on_road_hrs))) AS on_rh,  
   date AS date3
 FROM service_data
   OUTER JOIN numbers on numbers.n = service_data.date
 WHERE date >= (select MAX(date) FROM service_data)  - INTERVAL 15 DAY
 GROUP BY date  
 ORDER BY date ASC
```

And from experience, I believe this may need to be a `RIGHT JOIN` so all of the results from the `numbers` table are always included.

Comment: Will that require that I maintain identical rows of date data in both tables at all time or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The second table is temporary, so there's nothing to maintain. It lives just long enough to provide data for the query, then it's gone.

Comment: randy, are you saying to use the numbers in your sample temporary database or populate it with actual addresses that I currently have in mine?

Comment: It's an example. You need to grok it and combine it with your use-case to determine the actual right answer. If that doesn't do it, I have an alternative, but it's long, complex, I don't understand or remember where I got it...